# Series expansion using orthogonal polynomials?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I've just recently learned about Fourier Series, and I thought orthogonal polynomials could be used to expand functions as a series of powers of $x$ (in a similar way that of the trigonometric base for the Fourier Series). By the Best Approximation theorem, we can approximate a vector as a linear combination of the basis of  a subspace in which this vector is projected.
$$
c_n = \frac{\langle f(x), J_n(x) \rangle}{\langle J_n(x) , J_n(x) \rangle} \\\\
f(x) \sim \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {c_n x^n} 
$$
Where:
$
f(x) \in L^2([a, b], \mathbb K)
$

But the basis should be orthogonal, so by using Gram-Schmidt method we can ortogonalize the canonic base of the polynomials. Let's call each vector of the base as: $J_n(x)$. So we have the following:
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{N_n} \int_{a}^{b} {f(x)  \bar{J_n}(x) dx}
$$
Where: $N_n = \langle J_n(x) , J_n(x) \rangle$

This only holds for the interval: $[a, b]$. My Question is: Could this interval be made non-finite, for example from: $(-\infty, \infty)$?
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{N_n} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {f(x)  \bar{J_n}(x)  dx}
$$
Also, it is reasonable to define $J_n(x)$ as such? This set of polynomials should exist, so I see no problem, no? Is there any mistake I made or contradiction on the reasoning?
In other words, can you have a infinite radius of convergence and
expand the function, $f(x)$, in a similar way as a Taylor series, but using this basis?

Comment: one problem you will face is that $\langle p, p\rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} \bar p(x) p(x) dx$ will not be finite for any polynomial $p$.

Comment: With the proper weighting function, sure. For example, the Hermite and Laguerre polynomials are defined using Gaussian and Gamma weightings respectively.